# How to set TableLayout's cells vertical & horizontal alignments

Tags: java, swing, tablelayout

Is there a way to **set alignments in a TableLayout's cells**?

If I want a component in a cell set to for example right bottom?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of using [TableLayoutConstraints](http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/TableLayoutConstraints.html):

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import layout.TableLayout;
import layout.TableLayoutConstraints;

public class TableLayoutCellAlignmentExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example of TableLayout");
        frame.setSize(700, 400);

        double size[][] = {{200,200,200}, // Columns
            {100,100,100}}; // Rows

        frame.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));


        String[] labels = {
            "should be TOP LEFT",
            "should be TOP CENTER",
            "should be TOP RIGHT",
            "should be MIDDLE LEFT",
            "should be MIDDLE CENTER",
            "should be MIDDLE RIGHT",
            "should be BOTTOM LEFT",
            "should be BOTTOM CENTER",
            "should be BOTTOM RIGHT",
        };

        frame.add(new JButton(labels[0]), new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 0, 0, 0, TableLayout.LEFT, TableLayout.TOP));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[1]), new TableLayoutConstraints(1, 0, 1, 0, TableLayout.CENTER, TableLayout.TOP));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[2]), new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 0, 2, 0, TableLayout.RIGHT, TableLayout.TOP));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[3]), new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 1, 0, 1, TableLayout.LEFT, TableLayout.CENTER));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[4]), new TableLayoutConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, TableLayout.CENTER, TableLayout.CENTER));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[5]), new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 1, 2, 1, TableLayout.RIGHT, TableLayout.CENTER));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[6]), new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 2, 0, 2, TableLayout.LEFT, TableLayout.BOTTOM));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[7]), new TableLayoutConstraints(1, 2, 1, 2, TableLayout.CENTER, TableLayout.BOTTOM));
        frame.add(new JButton(labels[8]), new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 2, 2, 2, TableLayout.RIGHT, TableLayout.BOTTOM));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]